# Bootstrap - Set textbox value on modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to bind the event 'show' in my modal but nothing happens when it's shown.
Here's the code that was supposed to work.
The alert is not beeing displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $('#myModal').bind('show',function()
            {
                alert('howdy');
                $(".modal-body #nome").val('bosta');
            });
        </script>
```

Modal window code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Minha Conta</h3>
            </div>



            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="mConta">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required="">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>



            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where do you put your js, before or after the html code you posted?

Comment: So, the time the script executes, your modal doesn't exist so no binding takes place. You should follow Sushanth's answer.

Comment: I only voted because of 'bosta' haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to encase the code inside `DOM ready event` if your script is in the **header section**.

```
$(function() {
  $('#myModal').bind('show',function(){
      alert('howdy');
      $("#nome").val('bosta');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer didn't work for me but this one did;

```
$("#mymodal #mymodal-label").html("My New Title");
```