# Pre-populate modal textarea with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently a button opens a modal that includes a text box. I need have that text box pre-populated, so I have attempted to mess around with the modal with no luck.

I have tried the following and nothing appears to happen.

```js
function testFunc(){
    $('#contactUsDlg').modal('show');
    $('#contactUsDlg').on('shown.bs.modal', function {
       $('#message-text').text("test");
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="btn-ask" id="nonconform-btn" data-form-action-url="${newMessageUrl}"
                                data-pns="<%=OrderStatusPortletConstants.MESSAGE_CENTER_PORTLET_NAMESPACE %>"
                                data-use-ajax="true"
                                class="btn btn-submit btn-ask contact-us-dlg"
                                data-hidden-fields="message-order-id,message-source-url"
                                data-message-order-id="${selectedOrder.id}" data-message-source-url="${sourceUrl}" >
                                Contact Us
</button>
```

Comment: If you are using JQuery and have the ID of the text field and the button being clicked, why don't you just say something like `$('#buttonId').on('click', function() { $('#textFieldID').text('Whatever you want to say'); });`
Should do what you want just fine.

Comment: I've tried that. My guess is that since the modal is not shown yet, it isn't adding the text. Because if I open the modal first, I can type the jquery command $('#textField').text('whatever') in the console when inspecting the page, and it works.

Comment: If it's not showing with that solution check out the first solution on this link.  Should give you what you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227049/bootstrap-set-textbox-value-on-modal-window

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution basen on your snippets (not complete, IMHO)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contactUsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var text = $(e.relatedTarget).data('default-text');
    $(this).find('#message-text').text(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<button type="button" name="btn-ask" class="btn btn-submit btn-ask contact-us-dlg" data-form-action-url="${newMessageUrl}" data-pns="<%=OrderStatusPortletConstants.MESSAGE_CENTER_PORTLET_NAMESPACE %>" data-use-ajax="true" data-hidden-fields="message-order-id,message-source-url"
data-message-order-id="${selectedOrder.id}" data-message-source-url="${sourceUrl}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactUsModal" data-default-text="Initial contact us textarea modal content">
  Contact Us
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="contactUsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactUsModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still no luck. I know the scripts are running fine because I can run a simple alert to show it's fine. The problem is that trying to use an onclick event for the button tries to insert the text before the modal shows. Both the show.bs.modal and shown.bs.modal don't seem to work.

Comment: Why not add the text into the data-default-text attribute?

Comment: In the button? Not sure how to specify between the two different text boxes then. If you mean in the html creating the modal, it's shared by multiple other pages and i'd only like this text to be set if this specific button is clicked.

Comment: The default-text goes into button attribute named `data-default-text="Default text here"`

Comment: Where would it be placing that text though? In the button? Need a way to specify #message-text to populate the textbox in the modal

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should look into using jQuery UI. Here you can use something like the following:

```
<script src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<link href='jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>
<link href='jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>

<input id='mybutton' type='button' value='click me' />
<div id='result'>
    <p id='firstp'></p>  
    <p id='secondp'></p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#result').dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('#resultp').html('[this is my text]');
        }
    });
});
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(evt) {
    $('#secondp').html('[this is my second text]');
});
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason this causes my button to only pop-up the modal if I refresh the page each time. But does not populate the textarea

Comment: I've updated my answer to let you update a text field after the window opens. The window will now open right away, allowing you to click the button when it's open. Note, however, that the window is no longer a true modal window, but a dialog at this point.